# Google App engine deploy python project 502 bad gateway error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I've created a virtualenv in GAE, and setup the Flask project
When I execute "python3 main.py", the default route works fine, but when I execute "gcloud app deploy" and browse the page, 502 Bad Gateway shows.

I try to find the error log by execute "gcloud app logs read"
2017-10-22 08:21:53 default[XXXXXXXXXX]  "GET /" 502
2017-10-22 08:21:54 default[XXXXXXXXXX]  "GET /favicon.ico" 502

Only these message is shown

This is the app.yaml:

```html
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?